# Convering latitude and longitude of starting point of line from Lambert to DMS in QGIS

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, convert, latitude-longitude, degrees-minutes-seconds

I know how to convert Lambert to DMS latitude for points in a shapefile, i.e.:

```
y(transform($geometry, 'EPSG:31370', 'EPSG:4326'))
```

It works fine.

I want to make a similar transformation for points part of a line shapefile to extract the `start` and the `end` coordinates.

I understand I have to work with `$y_at(0)` and `y_at(-1)`, but I get the Lambert coordinates, but do not know how to transform them. I tested different ways, but without success, always an error.

How do I transform them correctly?

Comment: "tested in different ways" is rather unspecific. Please provide relevant code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are built-in functions to get the start and end points:

```
y(
    transform(
        geometry:=start_point($geometry),   -- use the `start_point` or `end_point` function here
        source_auth_id:=@layer_crs,         -- get the CRS of the current layer
        dest_auth_id:='EPSG:4326'
    )
)
```

results in `51.0664896971647`

Comment: Nice exactly what I was looking for ! Thank you very much.

Comment: Nice exactly what I was looking for ! Thank you very much. Imeasure my level of ignorance of the formula capabilities of Qgis. I definitely need a training on that! Are trainings available for starting learning the functions of QGis?

Comment: @ClaudeVer, please, do not forget about ["What should I do when someone answers my question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)